# Docker :: How to transfer a docker image from one mac system to another without docker hub

Tags: docker, docker-image

Am working in a restricted environment where access to docker hub is prohibited. Is there a way to transfer a docker image from one mac system to another without using docker hub ?

Comment: are you able to host a private docker registry in your environment?

Comment: There is also the option to `docker save ...` an image to a `.tar` file, take it with an external drive to the other mac and then use `docker load ...`